# Disabling Grub Bootloader on Ubuntu Installation

Tags: mac, bootloader, macosx

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 that I wish to install Ubuntu on. However, when I last installed it, it automatically installed the GRUB bootloader. And my main OS being macOS 10.13.6 running on an NVMe in a PCIe adapter. And even after I wiped the HD that Ubuntu was installed on, whenever I tried to boot to my NVMe running macOS; I would get a warning saying that it couldn't boot. And I would have to hold down the option key to get to the drive selector. Where I would boot to the NVMe. After I wiped the NVMe, it was fine and I haven't had an issue since.

However, I'd like to reinstall Ubuntu without the GRUB bootloader so I don't have this issue again. I tried following several guides online, but it never worked. I was wondering if someone could provide some insight on how to do this correctly.

Thanks,
Conrad

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu cannot install without GRUB. It is the bootloader, from their website:

> Briefly, a boot loader is the first software program that runs when a
> computer starts. It is responsible for loading and transferring
> control to the operating system kernel software (such as the Hurd or
> Linux). The kernel, in turn, initializes the rest of the operating
> system (e.g. GNU).

What you *can* do, [(source)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048300/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-without-grub) is to physically remove the hard drive, then install Ubuntu on the external device. The next time you start your computer (with hard disk restored) you can enter Ubuntu through F9

Comment: I would probably do the install as you described, which will force Ubuntu not to pollute NVMe drive. But it is not exactly true that Ubuntu can't be installed without Grub. It requires touchy procedure, Ubuntu Base, and then manually installing bootloader or adding entry for Ubuntu to existing bootloader (doesn't have to be Grub). But as I mentioned, it's not for the general public

Answer (score 0):

While I generally like the answer about installing Ubuntu with your NVMe drive disconnected, maybe that's not an option for you. So my alternate would be - why not install Ubuntu as VM inside MacOS?

MacOS is unixoid, so many of same tools exist. I went looking for KVM/QEMU and here is one link (can't try, don't own Mac):
https://opensource.com/article/20/9/try-linux-mac

Pick your choice of Virtualbox or QEMU, look for Mac specific tutorial , and you will have Ubuntu in VM in under an hour. And bo damage to your Mac partitions!

Performance is generally quite good, as long as you have enough RAM (memory).

If you don't want virtualization, go with disk removal.

P.S. Also, if you can't or don't want to remove your NVMe, nor bother with VMs, you can install Ubuntu on some other PC, to external drive, or USB stick, and then just plug it layer to your Mac and boot via boot selection menu. Grub will be on external disk that way as well.