# How to stop Ubuntu Installer detecting Windows/ignoring to avoid problems with existing boot managers

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mac

Is it possible to tell the Ubuntu installer to NOT look for Windows/ignore it (but leave it intact), so that it doesn't attempt to use GRUB.

Related:

[How to restore Startup Manager Bootcamp option to point at Windows partition - GRUB overrided Startup Manager when Ubuntu installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367635/how-to-restore-startup-manager-bootcamp-option-to-point-at-windows-partition-g)

Comment: Thank you mook765, I would want to agree and can you elaborate on the basis for your comment, please? For example, please share reading materials that form that opinion that could me, or your own practical experience. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't read carefully, my mistake. What is described in the link provided is a problem specific to Apple, I think your question is placed well there on AskDifferent. Cross-posting is not very appreciated on StackExchange.

Comment: +1 upvote from me for your honesty mook765. There are 2 parts to this problem, mook765, one is with Ubuntu and how it installs on a mac (hence posting here) and also the Apple startup manager itself and how it 'finds' and 'connects to' the OS partitions, hence my posting there. I've also been upfront and honest about the 2 posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader)

Comment: "Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader" - no, not really. That question is to restore Windows bootloader after installing Ubuntu. My question is about stopping Ubuntu installer from using GRUB in the first place. But +1 upvote from me to you on your comment, karel, for your good effort - no harm in knowing related but not exactly similar problems to encourage lateral thinking!

Comment: To install Ubuntu in EFI-mode without the boot-loader you have to run a live session ( `Try Ubuntu without installing`) and in the session, run `sudo ubiquity -b`. But how are you going to boot Ubuntu without Grub?

Comment: What do you think about living with Grub. Grub can be configured to boot to Windows by default and the timeout can be reduced. As far as I understand, all three OS are able to boot and configuring Grub might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Thank you but no, mook765. I'm happy to have GRUB just for Ubuntu. But I don't want it interfering with anything else on my system. It shouldn't have to. My question was about that.