# Change the bootloader from grub to windows boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have an old pc, isn't in UEFI but in BIOS, I have Windows 11 and ubuntu, for the bootloader I have GRUB; It's possible change it to Windows Boot Manager??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader)

Comment: I did not think Windows 11 could work on old computers nor on BIOS based systems? From grub you can boot Windows if Windows is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk. But Windows cannot boot Linux systems.

Comment: How old is old? Last week or 10 years ago?

Comment: @oldfred it says you can install Win 11 in legacy but it quite a bit of work. https://www.minitool.com/news/install-windows-11-legacy-bios-mode.html

Comment: If system is old, then Windows may not run well. Many with very old systems want Linux as it is more lightweight. But now even full Ubuntu is heavier like Windows and older systems need a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I like and use Kubuntu which is more middleweight but works well for me.